# appending Hash fragment after the path in setcookie function PHP

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie, cookie-path

I'm trying to set path in setcookie for my websites cookie, which contains a string followed by #wall , I could see path only till the first string, it's not accepting the # fraction of the path.

code goes like this:

```
 $wall = array(
     $this->database,
     $this->response['grouplist'][0],
     $this->username
 );

 setcookie(
     "wall",
     json_encode($wall),
     time() + 3600 * 24 * 1000 ,
     "/" + $this->database + "/#wall",
     ".mywebsite.com",
     0
 );

 session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.mywebsite.com');
```

output :

```
mywebsite.com   /S71c9524b57ab1b3383bcb14478b570b6      2019-07-16T06:37:55.065Z        92
```

Answer (score 1):

### Fragment is not a part of Path

The `#` character specifies the *fragment* part of a URL ([RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3)):

```
  URI         = scheme ":" hier-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]

  hier-part   = "//" authority path-abempty
              / path-absolute
              / path-rootless
              / path-empty
```

So the fragment (`wall`, particularly) is a different part of URL, and is *not* considered as part of the [*path*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3):

> The path is terminated by the first question mark ("?") or number sign
> ("#") character, or by the end of the URI.

Moreover, fragments depend on the document MIME type and are evaluated by the user agent ([RFC 3986, 3.5. Fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5)), i.e. fragments are never sent to the server:

> ...the fragment identifier is not used in the scheme-specific
> processing of a URI; instead, the fragment identifier is separated
> from the rest of the URI prior to a dereference, and thus the
> identifying information within the fragment itself is dereferenced
> solely by the user agent...

In other words, URL fragments are not supposed to work in the cookie `Path` attributes, and the server is not supposed to know anything about fragments.

### PHP syntax

Also note, `+` is an arithmetic operator, so your `"/" + $this->database + "/#wall"` is evaluated to `0`. If you meant concatenation, use the `.` (dot) operator instead:

```
$s = 'abc';
echo "/" + $s + "/#wall", PHP_EOL;
echo "/" . $s . "/#wall", PHP_EOL;
echo "/{$s}/#wall", PHP_EOL;
```

*Output*

```
0
/abc/#wall
/abc/#wall
```

So you should replace your "arithmetic" expression with `"/{$this->database}/#wall"`.

### It *may* work... sometimes

I have tested how the current version of Mozilla Firefox processes cookies for a path with different fragments. As it turns, it actually writes the cookies into `document.cookie` for different fragments, but one has to hard-reload the page in order to update the cookies. So I doubt that this is a useful feature.